# jQuery difference between offset().top and element.offsetTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between

```
$(this).offset().top
```

and

```
this.offsetTop
```

?

The element in question (this), is an img element.

I try to find the equivalent of the jQuery version.

Comment: Is it hard to look at the source code?

Comment: depends on what `this` is.

Comment: And to humour you (also because I wanted to know too) here is the source code https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery `offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

[`HTMLElement.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop)

offsetTop returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

[jQuery `position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

[Getting the position of the element to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: That code example is buggy and doesn't work well in some browsers (for example Mobile Chrome on iOS). Please use this much simpler version instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222246/1025702